# When I try to add a new page it gives me an error

Tags: beamer, errors, presentations

I'm using LaTeX to make a document for the first time, so I started off by just using a template and just editing text to make it as easy as possible for me. However, I've stumbled across a problem.

Here's is the (unedited) template I'm working with: https://www.writelatex.com/208274qlltfp.

My problem is that I can't add a new page to this template, no matter what I try. Most of the times I get an error saying 'no end is found' or something similar. How would I add a new page to this template?

This is the end of the document:

```
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Of course I am not too familiar with LaTeX, but judging from the template itself I assumed `\begin{frame}` meant a new page. But when I put that between `\end{frame}` and `\end{document}` (for example `\begin{frame}{Example}`. I get the following error:

```
job aborted, no legal \end found
```

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) here, instead of linking to writelatex.com? It would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Jubobs I'll add one, I'm not sure if I can locate the problem though.

Comment: What ccommand are you using for adding a new page? `\newpage` ?

Comment: \begin{frame}{somethingrandom}. I tried just using \\ too, didn't work either.

Comment: @MWord: For an empty frame you can use `\frame{}`

Comment: Each `\begin{frame}` needs to be balanced by an `\end{frame}`.  The material on the page (slide) goes between these two commands.  I say "slide" as the document class your are using is designed for presentations, not ordinary texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `\begin` must have an `\end`. When you add a new slide with `\begin{frame}`, you also have to close that slide with `\end{frame}`. The contents of the slide is written between the two, e.g.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of the slide}

This is the text in the slide
\end{frame}
```